# Получение поля из класса одного assembly в main другого assembly

Tags: c#, классы, rar

Доброго времени суток. Разбираю библиотеку NUnrar (https://nunrar.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) распаковки rar-файлов. Расскажу вкратце, как она работает.
Вот способ её запуска

```
RarArchive archive = RarArchive.Open(@"E:\RAR_testFunctions\NUnrar\123.rar");
foreach (RarArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(@"E:\RAR_testFunctions\NUnrar", Path.GetFileName(entry.FilePath));
    entry.WriteToFile(path);
}
```

после вызова метода `WriteToFile()` попадаем в один из классов `Unpack` (в зависимости от того, какие данные внтури архива). Так вот, в классе `internal abstract class Unpack15 : BitInput` есть поле `protected internal byte[] window;` в которое, в конечном итоге, и записываются байты при распаковывании. Класс `Unpack15` наследуется классами `Unpack20` и `Unpack`, в которых своим образом переопределяется этот поле. После того, как методы `Unpack` (каждый в своём классе) отработает, массив `window` заполняется данными. Я бы хотел этот массив возвращать через метод `WriteToFile()`, упомянутый выше, но не могу понять, как это грамотно сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Если будут нужны дополнительные сведения, с радостью предоставлю.

Comment: У RarArchiveEntry  есть же WriteTo(Stream, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы напрасно думаете что в этом поле содержится весь файл - на самом деле там содержится только его последний фрагмент.

Получить файл в виде массива байт проще через метод `WriteTo`:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
entry.WriteTo(ms);
```

Теперь из потока можно содержимое файла: `ms.ToArray()`. Или же можно сбросить позицию в ноль (`ms.Position = 0`) и читать содержимое файла из потока.

Если вам нужно чтобы файл все же оказался на диске - его можно записать вот так:

```
using (var file = File.OpenWrite(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.CopyTo(file);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Так действительно логичнее.